# How does PyTorch Tensor.index_select() evaluates tensor output?

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

I am not able to understand how complex indexing - non contiguous indexing of a tensor works. Here is a sample code and its output

```
import torch

def describe(x):
  print("Type: {}".format(x.type()))
  print("Shape/size: {}".format(x.shape))
  print("Values: \n{}".format(x))


indices = torch.LongTensor([0,2])
x = torch.arange(6).view(2,3)
describe(torch.index_select(x, dim=1, index=indices))
```

Returns output as

> Type: torch.LongTensor Shape/size: torch.Size([2, 2]) Values:
> tensor([[0, 2],
> [3, 5]])

Can someone explain how did it arrive to this output tensor?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the first (`indices[0]` is `0`) and third (`indices[1]` is `2`) tensors from `x` on the first axis (`dim=0`). Essentially, [`torch.index_select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.index_select.html) with `dim=1` works the same as doing a direct indexing on the second axis with `x[:, indices]`.

```
>>> x
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]])
```

So selecting columns (since you're looking at `dim=1` and not `dim=0`) which indices are in `indices`. Imagine having a simple *list* `[0, 2]` as `indices`:

```
>>> indices = [0, 2]

>>> x[:, indices[0]] # same as x[:, 0]
tensor([0, 3])

>>> x[:, indices[1]] # same as x[:, 2]
tensor([2, 5])
```

So passing the indices as a `torch.Tensor` allows you to index on all elements of indices directly, i.e. columns `0` and `2`. Similar to how NumPy's indexing works.

```
>>> x[:, indices]
tensor([[0, 2],
        [3, 5]])
```

---

Here's another example to help you see how it works. With `x` defined as `x = torch.arange(9).view(3, 3)` so we have *3* rows (a.k.a. `dim=0`) and *3* columns (a.k.a. `dim=1`).

```
>>> indices
tensor([0, 2]) # namely 'first' and 'third'

>>> x = torch.arange(9).view(3, 3)
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]])

>>> x.index_select(0, indices) # select first and third rows
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [6, 7, 8]])

>>> x.index_select(1, indices) # select first and third columns
tensor([[0, 2],
        [3, 5],
        [6, 8]])
```

*Note*: `torch.index_select(x, dim, indices)` is equivalent to `x.index_select(dim, indices)`